# Displaying videos in Django Template: Media Link

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-models

Currently trying to pull a video from a model, however it appears to be unable to locate the correct url by adding the media directory to the front of the pulled URL.

Am I pulling the url from the model correctly?

[Code + Generated HTML + Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLbnK.png)

Settings.py (Media section)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py (In app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.video_form_upload, name='highlights'),
    path('outputs', views.video_output, name='output')
]
```

UPDATE

video_output.html

```
{% extends 'highlights/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for video in highlights %}
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            {% load static %}
            <source src="{% static "{{ video.highlight.url }}" %}" type="video/mp4"></source>
              Your browser does not support the video tag
          </video>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT VIDEO URL

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>

    <source src="/media/%7B%7B%20video.highlight.url%20%7D%7D" type="video/mp4"></source>
      Your browser does not support the video tag
  </video>
```

Comment: Are you using the development server?

Comment: Can you share your settings for media?

Comment: as in debug mode? Yes it's set to True. The HTML page outputs as grey video control panels. Updated post with media settings.

Comment: And you have the static url/view added to your url patterns?

Comment: hm no, that could be the issue
Updated post with the urls.py code

Answer (score 0):

[You need to add the media URL to your urlpatterns in development.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you, on the right track!
I've updated the code with the static framework but am now unable to pull through the url value. Updated main post with the new html code and resulting video links.